# Loading Native Managed and C++ DLL within IIS 7 for WCF Project On Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7

I have WCF service developed in C# for with .NET framework 4.0 for IIS v7. My service **using** some managed VC++.NET DLL's which internally relies on some native C++ DLL's.

Now I have following options to proceed;

1) Publish all my managed DLL's in GAC (Global Repository)
2) set PATH environment variable, re-start my machine so that IIS (7) server can pick up the changes.

But client does not want both of the above solution because of following reasons;
1) They do not want anything available globally
2) Setting PATH, re-start the machine for every service deployed....NAAAAAH!!!!

So I researched and then I found I can set the environment on runtime, so I added some  properties within my Web.config file and thought of appending my environment for each service on runtime. But the problem is that where should I write this peace of code as if I append this code in service class IIS will fail as it will try to resolve all the dependencies but fail as my code is not ran yet.

Now I want, a way to split my code which set up the environment in separate class for each service on startup of the service and called that in the end when we un-deploy.

I am not sure if it is even possible?

**P.S Please bare in mind I am new to WCF and .NET stuff.**

Your help and comments will be appreciated.

--

SJunejo

Comment: Can you explain " I added some properties within my Web.config file and thought of appending my environment for each service on runtime"

Comment: Also  "separate class for each service on startup of the service and called that in the end when we un-deploy" what you want to un-deploy ?

Comment: I have added <appSettings><add key="external_lib_path" value="C:\" /></appSettings>, wrote a simple function which retrieve current PATH env and append my external_lib_path into PATH, the problem is that I want to write this function in some class which is other than my WCF service impl comes before service impl is loaded. The best example I can give is like we have ServiceLifecycle interface available in axis2 framework.
The other thing I am concerned is will IIS consider these new appended PATH to load my Native C++ lib?

Answer (score 0):

If yout don't set the Delay Load Property all referenced unmanaged DLLs will be loaded before your global.asax code is executed, so it's still looking in the wrong place.

You should follow all steps in Option 2b) if you want it to work.